# Rename columns in nested lists and row bind

Tags: r, plyr

I've a nested list of objects that I'd like to first rename some variables and row bind its object, but selecting only some variables.
In the example below, I'd like to rename columns `A` to `a` in the second object, and `w` to `x` in the third object to, then row bind all three object selecting only columns `a` and `x` using.

Data:

```
df <- list(structure(list(a = 1:3, 
x = c(-1.99, -1.11, -0.34), 
y = c("C", "B", "A")), .Names = c("a", "x",                                                                                                  "y"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                                                              -3L)), structure(list(a = 1:3, x = c(-0.44, -1.07,                                                                                                                                                                                                  -0.23)), .Names = c("A", "x"), class = c("tbl_df",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)), 
structure(list(a = 1:3, x = c(-0.62, -0.60, -0.06), 
y = c(3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("a", "w", "y"), class = c("tbl_df",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

List structure:

```
   > lapply(df, names)
[[1]]
[1] "a" "x" "y"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "x"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "w" "y"
```

Then, row binding then:

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ldply(df, data.frame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `purrr` (`map`), `dplyr`(`rename`,`select`,`bind_rows`,`%>%`) and magrittr (`%<>%`,`%>%`) ):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df[[2]] %<>% rename(.,a = A)
df[[3]] %<>% rename(.,x = w)
df %>% map_df(. %>% select("a","x"))
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#       a     x
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 -1.99
# 2     2 -1.11
# 3     3 -0.34
# 4     1 -0.44
# 5     2 -1.07
# 6     3 -0.23
# 7     1 -0.62
# 8     2 -0.60
# 9     3 -0.06
```

Or in base R:

```
names(df[[2]])[names(df[[2]]) == "A"] <- "a"
names(df[[3]])[names(df[[3]]) == "w"] <- "x"
do.call(rbind,lapply(df,"[",c("a","x")))
```

Comment: Maybe mention `%<>% ` is from `magrittr`, not `tidyr` or `dplyr`

Comment: Actually there was no `tidyr` there, but `map` come from `purrr`

Comment: Also, you could use `map_df` (which uses `bind_rows()` internally) instead of `map()` ... `bind_rows()`

Comment: Beautiful, I didn't know this one, I edited to use it

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that with:

```
library(plyr)
df = lapply(df, function(x) {plyr::rename(x,c("A"="a","w"="x"),warn_missing = F)})
df2 <- ldply(lapply(df, function(x) {x[,c("a","x")]}), data.frame)
```

Output:

```
  a     x
1 1 -1.99
2 2 -1.11
3 3 -0.34
4 1 -0.44
5 2 -1.07
6 3 -0.23
7 1 -0.62
8 2 -0.60
9 3 -0.06
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you think I must pinpoint for the object position as `colnames(df[[2]])[1]="a"` or may I use the name of column instead? This is important, because my real data object has more than 500 lists, say that I have to rename about 100 of them... It would be nice to have a more efficient approach, if it exists. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Hi Marie-Eve, please see the addition to my answer, which should cover that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea could be to create a named vector `v` with the replacement values, loop over your list, rename if there is a match and select the desired columns.

```
v <- c("a" = "A", "x" = "w")

map_df(df, .f = ~ rename_if(
  .x, 
  .p = names(.x) %in% v, 
  .f = funs(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(., v, names(v), vectorize_all = FALSE))) %>% 
    select(names(v))
)
```

Which gives:

```
## A tibble: 9 x 2
#      a     x
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1 -1.99
#2     2 -1.11
#3     3 -0.34
#4     1 -0.44
#5     2 -1.07
#6     3 -0.23
#7     1 -0.62
#8     2 -0.60
#9     3 -0.06
```